# Using Spark on Hive via Eclipse

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

We are using JDBC APIs to connect to HIVE through Eclipse programs to access hive tables, below is the code:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FetchHiveData_test {

private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  @Test
  public void  FetchHiveDataMethod() {
  ResultSet hiveres=null;
  try {
      System.out.println("Inside Hive Method");
      Class.forName(driverName);

      /*********** Hive ***************/
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://XXXXX:20000", "xxxxxx", "yyyyy");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql="select count(*) from table";
    hiveres = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = hiveres.getMetaData();
    int numCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
   for(int j=1;j<=numCols;j++){
        System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(j)+" ");
    }

    while (hiveres.next()) {

        //Print one row          
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= numCols; i++){

              System.out.print(hiveres.getString(i) + " "); //Print one element of a row

        }

          System.out.println();//Move to the next line to print the next row.           

            }

  } catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStackTrace();

}

}}
```

Methods [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) makes use of spark context however not sure where it takes the server name and credentials, how can I modify the above program to make use of spark? This is to make our queries to run faster as the JDBC APIs are bit slow.

Spark Code:

```java
import java.util.List; 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf; 
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD; 
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext; 
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function; 
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSchemaRDD; 
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.Row; 
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.api.java.JavaHiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 

public class SparkTest {

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Test
  public void f() {
    final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("xxxxx:20000").setAppName("HiveConnector");
    final JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaHiveContext hiveCtx = new JavaHiveContext(sparkContext); 
    JavaSchemaRDD rdd = hiveCtx.sql("Select count(*) from table"); 
        JavaRDD<Integer> keys = rdd.map(new Function<Row, Integer>() { 
            public Integer call(Row row) { return row.getInt(0); } 
            }); 
    List<Integer> res= keys.collect(); 
    for(Integer val:res){ 
            System.out.println("val "+val); 
   } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server and you will be able to access it through jdbc like in hive.

Note: This might not support all hiveQl.

Comment: Is it again beeline CLI ? I want to access it through java program.

Comment: This will execute your queries over spark rather than hive which will be faster.

Comment: Your current program should run as it is.

Comment: Is there a way to run spark via eclipse?

Comment: You can run it only in local mode.
add this as your maven dependency 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/1.6.0

Comment: added the jar and spark code as above, but while running am getting the "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;" error

Comment: You need to add all dependencies not only one jar. Try to build using some tool like maven.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104162/discussion-between-vinod-and-pankaj-arora).

Comment: what is your skypeid?